How to get SQL server name which is configured in SSRS server with PowerShell Code?
In SSRS server data source is in encrypted file i.e rsreportserver.config
I am expecting a PowerShell script to get the SQL server name that is configure in SSRS configuration.
Please suggest if we get the server  name with using PowerShell Sctipt.
